# Advice For WCF-based Server Combining Queries And Business Operations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-data-services

**Background**

I've been killing some neurons lately with this. I would like to make a multi-tier application for parcel services like UPS and such. Long story short, the backend will be a WCF-based server while the consumer will be an ASP.NET MVC application. The idea is that the backend will handle all business operations (like adding a new shipment, editing existing shipments, carriers and such) but will provide the consumer with data in form or queries.

**And the Issue Is...?**

My plan for business operations is that the consumer should pass all the information required to complete the operation (pretty much like a model, i.e. for adding shipments, the consumer would send all the required information for those shipments.) Now, my actual issue is with data querying.

The consumer application should be able to display the backend-provided data in anyway it desires, not limited by a DTO. For example, when listing shipments, I only want to show a grid with Name, ID, date shipped and such, not the entire shipment object graph.

How can the consumer application specify the data projection it needs to the WCF endpoint?

**Options**

I thought on creating several operation method overloads exposing different DTOs for different purposes. I.e.:

```
IList<ShipmentDetailsDTO> GetAllShipmentsAsDetailed(); 

IList<ShipmentListingItemDTO> GetAllShipmentsAsListingItems();
```

I dropped the idea since the backend is adapting to the consumer application needs, and this is not a good practice. The backend should be agnostic of the consumer.

Another option is to combine WCF data services for querying data and WCF regular services for business operations. This way the MVC application can project the data like a regular LINQ query against the WCF data services. Sounds quite elegant but I would like to hear a second opinion.

Any thoughts? What would you do if you were me? I need an elegant and practical solution for this.

Comment: Here is a blog post with part of nuget's solution (along with a stupid quirk of OData, that they needed to by pass). In effect they have an OData service for search based queries, and WCF Soap for, well SOAP. http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/how-odata-quirk-killed-nuget-server.html

Comment: An alternative would be to use MVC Web API for the backend, and produce a REST interface, through that (will WebAPI OData Queryable magic of course). The downside is that AFAIK .net REST consumer code is a bit rubbish. Also it takes a little more work to produce each service action.

Comment: Are there any downsides of using WebAPI instead of WCF? I mean, consumer-wise.

Comment: Yup...As I said. WebAPI is for creating rich REST interfaces. AFAIK the .net framework has yet to produce a good REST client library. The `WCF Data Services Client` is incompatible with WebAPI last I checked, which royally sucks, as it is the 'best' LinqToOData provider I know of.